# awk to output matches to separate files

Tags: awk

I am trying to combine the text in `$2` that is the same and output them to separate files with the match being the name of the new file.  Since the actual files are quite large I open each file, then close to save on speed and memory, my attempt is below.  Thank you :).

```
awk '{printf "%s\n", $2==$2".txt"; close($2".txt")}' input.txt **'{ print $2 > "$2.txt" }'**
```

**input.txt**

```
chr19:41848059-41848167 TGFB1:exon.2;TGFB1:exon.3;TGFB1:exon.4 284.611 108 bases
chr15:89850833-89850913 FANCI:exon.20;FANCI:exon.27;FANCI:exon.32;FANCI:exon.33;FANCI:exon.34 402.012 80 bases
chr15:31210356-31210508 FANC1:exon.6;FANC1:exon.7 340.914 152 bases
chr19:41850636-41850784 TGFB1:exon.1;TGFB1:exon.2;TGFB1:exon.3 621.527 148 bases
```

**Desired output for TGFB1.txt**

```
chr19:41848059-41848167 TGFB1:exon.2;TGFB1:exon.3;TGFB1:exon.4 284.611 108 bases
chr19:41850636-41850784 TGFB1:exon.1;TGFB1:exon.2;TGFB1:exon.3 621.527 148 bases
```

**Desired output for FANC1.txt**

```
chr15:89850833-89850913 FANCI:exon.20;FANCI:exon.27;FANCI:exon.32;FANCI:exon.33;FANCI:exon.34 402.012 80 bases
chr15:31210356-31210508 FANC1:exon.6;FANC1:exon.7 340.914 152 bases
```

EDIT:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{f = $3 ".txt";  close($3 ".txt")} print > f}' BMF_unix_loop_genes_IonXpress_008_150902_loop_genes_average_IonXpress_008_150902.bed > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/panels/BMF **/"$f".txt;**
bash: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/panels/BMF: Is a directory
```

Comment: [Redirecting Output of `print` and `printf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Redirection)

Comment: in the `awk` I added an edit to redirect the output.  Is that correct?  Thank you :).

Comment: Don't edit your post with an answer. Post an answer if you think it is useful and accept it. As to whether that's correct. Try it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just redefine your field separator to include a colon and then the file name would be in $3

```
awk -F '[ :]' '{f = $3 ".txt"; print > f}' input.txt
```

I've encountered problems with some awks where constructing the filename to the right of the redirection is problematic, which is why I'm using a variable. However the Friday afternoon beer cart has been around and I can't recall specific details :/

I wouldn't bother closing the files unless you're expecting hundreds or thousands of new files to be produced.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know :).

Comment: In the edit I added  an `awk` but am getting an error trying to redirect the new files to a directory.  Thank you :).  I also am expecting hundreds of files so added a close :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the second field to the desired field name.  This should do

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{close(p)} {split($2,f,":"); p=f[1]".txt"; print $0 > p }' file
```

Note that it won't produce your output exactly since you have a typo in one of the fields

```
$ ls *.txt
FANC1.txt  FANCI.txt  TGFB1.txt
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your BEGIN block?

Comment: Oops it must be the Friday afternoon beer cart :). Should be in the main body.